# Set Symfony translation domain for whole bundle

Tags: symfony5, symfony-translator

Is it possible to set the Symfony default translation domain for the whole bundle? By default a bundle uses the `messages` domain, which apparently breaks overriding the translations in Symfony > 4 (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/40014). Probably overriding works if the whole bundle has a domain like `my-bundle.<Translation file extension>`. Which can be overridden in the app-project in `translations/my-bundle.xliff`.

Or do you need to insert e.g. `{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}` into every single `.twig` file as seen in this bundle: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Registration/register_content.html.twig (Furthermore it also needs to be set before every call to the translator in controllers and services).

Preferably this could be set in the bundle class somewhere:

```php
class MyBundle extends Bundle {}
```

Comment: It is not possible to do that

Comment: If you want to create a specific domain, you'll have to add it every time you're using it.